# Set custom headers for Object Change Notifications

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

**Background:** In Google Cloud Storage I generate a Signed URL and use it to upload an object. I also have Object Change Notifications set up.

**Question:** Is there a way to set some custom headers when uploading an object via the Signed URL which will then be delivered in the request of the servlet which the Object Change Notification is posted to?

Comment: It's worth noting that GCS now also supports sending notifications via Cloud Pub/Sub, which you'll likely find easier to work with than Object Change Notifications.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Not sure how I feel about Cloud Pub/Sub yet... Also the docs aren't very good right now. So not sure.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't like the docs. Is there anything in particular about them that you wanted to see improvement in? There's a high level concepts page ( https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications ), as well as a Getting Started guide ( https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes ).

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Well I am using Cloud Endpoints (Java). I have a servlet which Object Change Notification pushes a notification to when I upload an object to GCS with a SignedURL. Then in the servlet I do various google app engine things. I haven't ran across how I would do the same with Cloud Pub/Sub.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Also, Not sure if this is true but I read here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-pubsub-push-with-cloud-endpoints-6a1adc36db9f `PubSub will make sure to keep the messages coming or back-off when your service can’t keep up. One caveat is that only one message is pushed at a time` So... is this scalable? Is what I was wondering.

Comment: You can use Cloud Pub/Sub notifications with Cloud Endpoints. That blog post you linked to is about how to do just that. And yes, it scales well, although if you plan on doing more than a few uploads per second, you may want to consider pulling messages in batches from Cloud Pub/Sub rather than having Cloud Pub/Sub push messages to you via Cloud Endpoints. When you pull messages, you can specify how many messages you want, so one call can bring back a hundred or more events.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Made a new question I was hoping you could take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358824/how-scalable-are-google-club-pub-sub-compared-object-change-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add key/value pairs to the `metadata` property of object metadata on upload:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource-representations

When the object change notification is delivered, the object's metadata will contain your custom metadata entries.

Comment: Does the Signed URL need to be a POST? I'm looking here (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object) it says `Uploads objects by using HTML forms.` - I've been testing things out and it looks like I cannot set metadata headers with a PUT. However, I am not using an HTML form to upload... Could you help me out?

Comment: See the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't answer my question of whether or not the signed URL needs to be a POST to upload custom headers... Can it be a PUT?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to fill in the custom metadata of the object using a PUT as well.