# How to send custom data with Cloud Pub/Sub when GCS object is uploaded via a Signed URL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I was able to set up Google Cloud Storage Cloud Pub/Sub notifications using:

`gsutil notification create -t [TOPIC_NAME] -m my-key:my-value -f json gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`

My App Engine servlet correctly gets a message every time an object is uploaded to GCS. I upload my object to GCS with a Signed URL.

However, I'm not sure how to set custom key-value pairs from my client when uploading an object with the Signed URL. The above `gsutil` command lets you set a key:value pair but it hard-codes it so that is not useful. In my client I want to set some key:value pair like `user : some-user` so then in my servlet I can do some extra App Engine stuff like write to a database.

I tried uploading some headers in the `metadata` tag as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource-representations) but getting those headers from the `HttpServletRequest` in the servlet didn't seem to work.

Also, how would I sent the `subscriptionUniqueToken` as well, since there is no explanation on how to do that.

Note: using `Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notion of a unique token is no longer necessary in most cases. Object change notifications offered them because they worked by sending unauthenticated HTTPS calls to a configurable endpoint. If that endpoint were discovered, a malicious user could also send such calls. However, Cloud Pub/Sub notifications publish messages to a topic as a known service account, and so long as no malicious third party is also granted publishing permission to that topic, they cannot interfere. If you want, you can include a unique token as a second protection mechanism, but it's generally not necessary.

"Client tokens" are a feature specific to Object Change Notifications. The equivalent with Cloud Pub/Sub integration are "custom_attributes", user-specified properties of a notification config that are attached as extra attributes to each notification. You could add a "unique_token" attribute and attach a value, if you wish.

When using signed URLs, setting custom metadata is done with HTTP headers beginning `x-goog-meta-`. For example, `x-goog-meta-stuff: Foo` will create a custom attribute pair "stuff: Foo".

Comment: @BlueBoy did you have to do anything special when you created your signed url when passing custom data?

Comment: @brandon-yarbrough any thoughts on above?

Comment: @raunak Yes, when signing a request with custom metadata, you need to include the headers in the signature and also have the client submit them. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#about-canonical-extension-headers